# Jersey JSON upload failure

Tags: json, jaxb, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I have an entity class looks like this.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class ImageSuffix {

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean canRead;

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean canWrite;

    @XmlValue;
    private String value;
}
```

An I wrote a JAX-RS resource class looks like this.

```java
@Path("/imageSuffixes")
public class ImageSuffixesResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<ImageSuffix> read() {
        // ...
    }

    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})    
    @PUT
    public void update(final List<ImageSuffix> imageSuffixes) {
        // ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{name: .+}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response readImageSuffix(@PathParam("name") final String name) {
        // ...
    }

    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @PUT
    @Path("/{name: .+}")
    public void updateImageSuffix(@PathParam("name") final String name,
                                  final ImageSuffix imageSuffix) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here are the results

```
GET /imageSuffixes     in application/xml
PUT /imageSuffixes     in application/xml
GET /imageSuffixes/png in application/xml
PUT /imageSuffixes/png in application/xml

GET /imageSuffixes     in application/json
PUT /imageSuffixes     in application/json FAIL: 400
    -> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request)
GET /imageSuffixes/png in application/json
PUT /imageSuffixes/png in application/json FAIL: fields don't get values
```

Here is the `/imageSuffixes in application/json`.

```js
{
    "imageSuffix": [
        {
            "$": "jpg",
            "@canRead": "true",
            "@canWrite": "true"
        },
        {
            "$": "bmp",
            "@canRead": "true",
            "@canWrite": "true"
        },
        {
            "$": "wbmp",
            "@canRead": "true",
            "@canWrite": "true"
        },
        {
            "$": "jpeg",
            "@canRead": "true",
            "@canWrite": "true"
        },
        {
            "$": "png",
            "@canRead": "true",
            "@canWrite": "true"
        },
        {
            "$": "gif",
            "@canRead": "true",
            "@canWrite": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the `/imageSuffixes/png in application/json`.

```js
{
    "$": "png",
    "@canRead": "true",
    "@canWrite": "true"
}
```

Is this normal or Jersey's fault?

When I lean on following dependency, it works with some different JSON output.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```js
{
    "canRead": true,
    "canWrite": true,
    "value": "png"
}
```

The real question is that GlassFish(with jersey) doesn't parse the JSON request which is what exactly he (or she) printed out.

Comment: I am not sure if  @Path("/{name: .+}") is the correct syntax.  Did you try  @Path("/name") "

Comment: What was the error message in your server logs?

Comment: @Abraham the path expression is ok, I believe.

Comment: @Perception `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request).`

Comment: Well I am going to assume that for your collection put, that you are passing in the inner array (the element associated with `imageSuffix`), because the outer structure is a JSON object. When you get past that, you will have a problem with the `$` attribute in the JSON not being able to be mapped to your POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minor changes your code works just fine for me. Note that in your current configuration, you are using the Jackson library for processing incoming/outgoing JSON messages. And by default, when deserializing data, Jackson will ***fail*** if it encounters unknown properties (aka, attributes that exist in your JSON, that do not have corresponding property mappings on your Java object). One way of avoiding this error is using a [`@@JsonIgnoreProperties`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class ImageSuffix {

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean canRead;

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean canWrite;

    @XmlValue;
    private String value;
}
```

It also appears that when testing your resource method that accepts a list of values, that you were sending a single object instead. Make sure you send an actual JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "$": "jpg",
        "@canRead": "true",
        "@canWrite": "true"
    },
    {
        "$": "bmp",
        "@canRead": "true",
        "@canWrite": "true"
    }
]
```

Lastly, in whatever test client you are using, do not forget to add request headers `Accept: application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: Using `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` is an work around. Can you please resolve why GF(jersey) doesn't understand what exactly she printed?

Comment: @JinKwon - so your situation is - when you use the JSON being retrieved from the GET method, and using it in the PUT method, that Jackson does not parse it?

Comment: @JinKwon - and side note, it looks like your Jersey deployment is using Jettison for its marshalling, which is why you see `@canRead` and `@canWrite`, instead of `canRead` and `canWrite`. Is there a particular reason you do not want to use Jackson?

Comment: No I didn't mean to use the Jackson. Yes, My situation is that a pure G/F which defaults whatever it ships with doesn't understands what she outputs.